# VS 2022 hangs after unloading a project everytime

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a react project which I need to unload from my solution because I build it separately.
Every time I try to unload that project, my VS 2022 goes into a hung state.
Has anyone experienced the same?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue since 17.8

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was experiencing this same thing until just now with VS 2022 Community v17.2.6.

I was trying to unload a GraphQL since I don't really care about that project, it's only on the same folder/repo.

I went into `Tools -> Get Tools and Features...` and uninstalled `Node.js development`. That did the trick, although I guess it might be because now it doesn't load the project to start with, it shows as "incompatible". Luckily I don't do any Node.js development in VS.

If yours is a Node.js project too you could try this, or maybe try a fresh install only including the most basic things to see if it works that way, and keep adding tools and features until you find which one is the problematic one.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on VS 2022 (17.8.1) having just C# projects within solution.

Repairing Visual Studio using the Visual Studio Installer did not help.

Comment: I have the same issue after update from 17.7 to 17.8.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2022 (17.8.4) having same issue.  I have uninstalled **node.js development** but this still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9 Preview 3
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-hangs-when-unloading/10505450